# About electrostatic pressure in a charged conductor

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

To calculate electrostatic pressure, force on an area of the conductor is required. So we calculate the electric field due to charges other than those on the small area on the conductor. Consider a charged conductor. The electric field due to charge on a small area S is E1 and due to rest of the charge is E2 (at points very close to the surface). In the diagram E1 is normal to the surface.  My question is why is the electric field due to the rest of the charge E2 parallel to E1 at point P1?[image]

Comment: P1 and P2 are very close to the conductor so the Electric field is nearly constant

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the property that electric field is always normal to the surface of charged conductor otherwise due to tangential component it will lead to potential difference between the surface but surface of
charged conductor is equipotential so it is not possible.

So in your question $E_1$ and $E_2 $ will always be parallel and normal to surface.